# SSAS Cube processing option which has greater performance

Tags: ssas

I have SQL 2012 tabular and multidimensional models which is currently been processed through SQL jobs. All the models are processing with 'Process Full' Option everyday. However some of the models are taking long time for processing. Can anyone teel which is the best processing option that will not affect the performance of the SQL instance.

Answer (score 0):

Without taking a look at you DB is hard to know but maybe I can give you a couple of hints:

It depends on how the data in DB is being updated. If all the fact table data is deleted and inserted every night, Process Full is probably the best way to go. But maybe you can partition data by date and proccess only the affected partitions.

On a multidimensional model you should check if aggregations are taking to much time. If so, you should consider redesign them.

On tabular models I found that some times having unnecesary big varchar fields can take huge amounts of time and memory to proccess. I found Kasper de Jonge's Server memory Analysis very helpful on identifying this kind of problems:
http://www.powerpivotblog.nl/what-is-using-all-that-memory-on-my-analysis-server-instance/bismservermemoryreport/